# Не могу разобраться что не так, ошибка root = Tk()

Tags: python-3.x

```
from Tkinter import *

def new_win():    
    win = Toplevel(root)

def close_win():
    root.destroy()

def new_frame():    

root = Tk()
root.title('Field')
root.geometry('300x400')

main_menu = Menu(root)

file_menu = Menu()

main_menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)

file_menu.add_command(label='SitesID', command=new_win)

file_menu.add_separator()

file_menu.add_command(label='Map', command=new_win)

file_menu.add_separator()

file_menu.add_command(label='Settings', command=new_win)

file_menu.add_separator()

file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=close_win)


edit_menu = Menu(root)

main_menu.add_cascade(label='Site', menu=edit_menu)

edit_menu.add_command(Label='Search', command=new_win)


root.config(menu=main_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

> ```
> root = Tk()
>        ^
> IndentationError: expected an indented block
> ```

Comment: Может быть ему отступы не нравятся?

Comment: Ну как бы по переводу да, но где именно уже мозг кипит

Comment: простите лажанулся, надо больше отдыхать

Answer (score 0):

У Вас все тело функции new_frame () написано без отступов. Сдвиньте весь этот текст, начиная с 
root = Tk() и до конца функции, на четыре пробела вправо.